# Kendo: Keep font-size of floatingLabel

Tags: css, angular, kendo-ui-angular2

When I use `floatingLabel` the label moves over the input field but the size of the label is reduced and I'd like the text to keep the original size (or change it to any other size).

What I do: with the following code:

```
  <kendo-textbox-container floatingLabel="First name">
    <input kendoTextBox />
  </kendo-textbox-container>
```

I obtain:

[image]

And when I write in it, I get:

[image]

As you can see, the font size is reduced.

I inspected the code and I saw there is a transformation, but if I write

```
  .k-textbox-container > .k-label {
    background: purple;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
```

in the `css` the font-size doesn't change, but it doesn't move on the textbox either.

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it!

[Here there is a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/kendo-angular-dateinput-afhefj) with the answer and a **bonus track**: how to pirouette the placeholder!

The main idea is to detect when the field is filled/focused/selected and apply the following css class:

```
  .placeholder.selected,
  .k-textbox:focus + .placeholder,
  .shifted-placeholder {
    transform: translate3d(-10px, -75%, 0);
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 0;
  }
```

A function

```
  onInput(value: any): void {
    this.value = value;
  }
```

in the `.ts` file is used to know if the field is filled or not.

Enjoy it and... **don't miss the pirouette**! :-D

Answer (score 1):

you can try the following code and set the font size you need in place of 30px.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <kendo-textbox-container floatingLabel="First name">
      <input kendoTextBox />
    </kendo-textbox-container>
  `,
  styles: ['.k-state-focused{font-size: 30px !important;}']
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

Comment: If works pretty well for the final result, but the transition is weird. It changes the font-size suddenly to 30 and then it reduces it. Also, when you write something in the input field and you focus out, the size turns small again. I'll see if I can fix it using this solution...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it has something to do with the transform css. Try this and see if it works

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
     <kendo-textbox-container floatingLabel="First name">
      <input kendoTextBox />
    </kendo-textbox-container>
    `,
  styles: ['.k-textbox-container > .k-label{transform: translate(1px, -3px) translate(-1px, -1.0714285714em) translate(-12.5%, -9.375%) scale(1);}']
})

export class AppComponent {
}
```